# Perl how to compare hash value against a list and returns keys matching

Tags: perl, hash

Consider this case:
I have a list:

```
@Value2CompareList
```

And I have a hash table:

```
%Hash2Check
```

Now I want to achieve the following:

```
if($Hash2Check{$keys} eq $ElementFromArray) {return matching keys}
```

How do I do it in a faster way without Loop?

Thanks folks!

Comment: You can't do it without a loop, because you're iterating elements. That's what a loop is. You might be able to do it with `grep`, but could you clarify? Are you checking each key against each array member?

Comment: Sorry maybe I make my situation more clear: I can iterate through array and I want the array elements to be compared against all the hash values and returns the matching key. Thanks

Comment: Hashes are for looking up data by **key**. If you are looking up data by **value**, you might want to reconsider your design decisions.

Comment: There are also a number of modules which can find intersection between lists/arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use grep inside a grep:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

my @Value2CompareList = qw( a b c d e f );
my %Hash2Check = (
    A => 'a',
    B => 'b',
    C => 'c');

say for grep {
    my $k = $_;
    grep $Hash2Check{$k} eq $_, @Value2CompareList
} keys %Hash2Check;
```

It's complex because the data structure is not suitable for what you need. An inverted hash would be much better:

```
my %Inverted = reverse %Hash2Check;
say for grep defined, @Inverted{@Value2CompareList};
```

This only works if the values are unique. If not, you need to create a hash of arrays:

```
my %Inverted;
while (my ($k, $v) = each %Hash2Check) {
    push @{ $Inverted{$v} }, $k;
}
say for map @$_, grep defined, @Inverted{@Value2CompareList};
```

Comment: Thanks bro. Your method works out fine, at least more faster than using nested loop. In my case the value is unique.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do it without a loop. You are iterating a list, and that's a loop.

But you can pretend a little, and use `grep`:

```
my @matches = grep { exists $Hash2Check{$_} } @Value2CompareList;
```

But be under no illusions - `grep` is still iterating the list. Each iteration, it sets `$_` to the current element, and checks if it exists in the hash.

Comment: `grep { $Hash2Check{$_} ? $_ : () }` translates to `grep { $Hash2Check{$_} }` when `$_` is true.

Comment: Yep. You're quite correct. I was getting muddled and thinking `map` returning the values. More correctly `exists` might be appropriate.